Can't load .bytes (binary) with Resources.Load<TextAsset> if the file contains a GIF
Before I start, let me insist that I do not want to put my files in StreamingAssets. I know it would work but that's not part of the requirements.
I need to read a binary resource. It's an animated GIF file. So I need to load it from the resources and access its bytes.
I thought I could rename it to Assets/Resources/myfile.bytes and then use
var myfile = Resources.Load<TextAsset>("myfile");

But this returns null. I tried many variants with different extensions too.
I suspect that whenever I drag a GIF file to Unity assets, it always recognizes the file type even if the extension is changed. I think that because it generates the file "myfile.bytes.gif.meta".
At this point I don't know what to do and I'm about to give up. Please give me a hand.
EDIT 1: This only happens on MacOS, not on Windows. Please let me know how to make it work on MacOS too.

I forgot to mention I'm on MacOS. It seems like the file type is not only decided by the extension on this operating system, but it's baked into the content of the file. When I add the file to Unity on Windows, it works fine. The meta file is correctly named "myfile.bytes.meta" and I can read the file with Resources.Load() with no issue.
But then whenever I open the project on Mac, the meta file is changed back and it doesn't work!

Are you sure that you actually changed the extension? Many OS, depending on the settings, may hide the actual extension. So adding .bytes to the name would not help when the OS keeps the original extension at the end. Given that you said there's a myfile.bytes.gif.meta file it would indicate that you added .bytes at the wrong spot. You should have myfile.gif.bytes and myfile.gif.bytes.meta. I'm not a Mac user, so renaming files is up to you.

@Bunny83 Not in this case since the extension ends up as "myfile.gif.bytes.gif.meta" (with gif twice). That was a good guess but no cigar.
I actually sent the file over Git to my Windows machine and then erased the .meta file to reimport the file and it then worked properly.

I found the solution!
It turns out, when you change file extension on MacOS, that the type of the file is not really changed but hidden. The trick is to open the file's information panel (command+i), and go to the Name and Extension section:

Then, just uncheck the box "Hide extension" and remove ".gif". A confirmation dialog will pop up, so just agree with the new extension. That's all!


Not every asset is a TextAsset. A gif image is recognised by Unity as an image and imported as Texture2D. So the actual asset is already the imported Texture2D. If you want to ship arbitrary data as TextAsset, you have to append either .txt, .bytes or any of the extensions mentioned here to your file name so Unity will actually treat them as TextAssets.
Keep in mind that the asset / resource name is always the filename without the (final) extension. So when you append .bytes and your file name becomes "MyFile.gif.bytes" the resource name should be "MyFile.gif".

But I did append .bytes. This works well on Windows, but not on MacOS. So it's a problem with Unity importing files on Mac. I need to trick it into treating the file as binary even though it's an image.
